# Create symlink of magento 1 "media" folder

Tags: magento-1.9, media, media-images, symlinks

I need to create a symlink of my magento1 "media" folder on another disk of my server because I need to make space on current disk. In which way can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a symbolic link you will need first to attach the other disk. After that copy the media folder to the new disk:

```
cp -r /path/to/media /mnt/new/drive
```

Rename media folder:

```
mv /path/to/media /path/to/oldmedia
```

Create symlink to new destination

```
ln -s /mnt/new/drive/media /path/to/media
```

Check that everything is fine, add some new pictures, verify they are created at new destination. Then delete old media folder

```
rm -rf /path/to/oldmedia
```

Comment: Hi sir, when you say "create symlink to new destination", what is /mnt/new/drive/media ? Is it the new folder that will contains "media" field?

Comment: Yes, you copy `media` folder to the other drive. `/mnt/new/drive` is just a sample path where your drive is mounted. And `/path/to/media` is the sample path to media folder inside your Magento root. You should substitute them with real paths.